# Align two columns with CSS

Tags: css, html

I have markup like

```
<div> <label for="a" class="float-left">column 1 row 1</label> <input type="text" value="column 2 row 1" id="a"  class="float-left"/>

<div class="float-clear"></div>

<div> <label for="b" class="float-left">longer column 1 row 2</label> <input class="float-left" type="text" value="column 2 row 2" id="b" />   

<div class="float-clear"></div>

<div> <label class="float-left" for="c">column 1 row 2</label> <input class="float-left" type="checkbox" id="c" />
```

How can I make column two rows to be aligned on the left, currently they are positioned depending on the length of the the text in the label? I don't want a full CSS grid just for this one place where I need alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want it this one place, you can do it with margin-left.

Another answer is to make your labels inline-block elements and give them all a set width.

Comment: Thanks daniel, but with margin-left the margin seems to start from the end of the left column. With different margin-left per row the second column in misaligned in different browsers.

Is inline-block supported in IE7, that's the browser my client uses?

Comment: Ah maybe you need to reset first with *{margin:0;padding:0;} (bad practice but just to make a point) to get it to work in all browsers. As for IE7, I'm not sure in this example, but I'd give it a try to begin with as it's the prettiest solution